# How will a suborbital flight country to country work?

Tags: sub-orbital

If a suborbital flight from NY to Beijing will cover about 7k miles in an hour, what will that trajectory be and at what speed (including the Earth's rotation)? Will most of the flight be above the Kármán line?

Comment: There probably wont be a simple answer to this, there are many options.

Comment: Note: 7,000 miles/hour is only 3.13 km/s. (Only on Space Exploration is over 3,000 meters/second an "only".)

Comment: Is this really about space exploration?

Comment: With a closer look at the [Help center](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/14537/33) I conclude that this question is on-topic.

Comment: my http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13815 and http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13866 don't directly answer this question, but may be helpful.